# How do I use NSMutableArray as a queue?

Tags: cocoa

I have NSMutableArray and used it like queue for waiting actions.

Example in array:

0: "Do something"
1: "Do something else"
2: "Do something 2"

When I used `[myarray removeObjectAtIndex:0]` the array is not reordering and next time when I use `[myarray objectAtIndex:o]` the result is `nil`.

How can I put "Do something else" in the first index and "Do something 2" in the second index when I remove "Do something"?

Comment: Can you post a code sample demonstrating what's not working?  removeObjectAtIndex: should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 10):

```
/* gcc -framework Cocoa myprogram.m -o myprogram */

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  NSMutableArray *array = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] 
                           initWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3",
                                            nil ]; /* don't forget nil */

  /* "pop" the first object */
  [ array removeObjectAtIndex:0 ];

  /* prints "2" as expected */
  NSLog( @"%@", [ array objectAtIndex: 0 ] );
}
```

Comment: The only issue is that you might expect an array pop to return the object popped, but removeObjectAtIndex does not return anything.

Answer (score 8):

I normally handle my queues in the reverse order but the effect is the same:

```
// somewhere in your code you insert into the queue (always at index 0)
[myArray insertObject:anObject atIndex:0];
```

then, elsewhere, you read from the queue:

```
// Process elements in the queue in a FIFO manner
while ([myArray count])
{
    id object = [myArray lastObject];

    // do something with object

    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:[myArray count] - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

NSArray already behaves the way you want, and in fact cannot contain nil. It sounds like your array might be somehow getting set to nil.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're not removing while iterating...

Answer (score 0):

> When I used [myarray removeObjectAtIndex:0] the array is not reordering and next time when I use [myarray objectAtIndex:o] the result is nil.

Your problem seems to be that you have a lower case O and not the number 0

Comment: That would just cause a compile error… unless the questioner actually has a variable named `o`, in which case the questioner would get either a valid object (though perhaps not the one the questioner expects) or an NSRangeException.